# JavaFX круглый ProgressBar

Tags: java, css, javafx, progress-bar, fxml

Суть вопроса такова, нужно сделать круглый прогресс бар. Пробовал создать на основе ProgressIndicator, не выходит ничего нормального. Нужна помощь.

Вот примерно, то чего я хочу добиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать также но через css, fxmal

Comment: Как вариант - нарисовать на канве

Answer (score 0):

Одним CSS тут не обойдешься, можете посмотреть реализацию круглого ProgressBar по [этой ссылке](https://github.com/torakiki/fx-progress-circle)